# what exactly is a string and an array in c and what is strlen() used for

Tags: c

I have read that string is an array of characters.Array can hold any datatype but string can have only characters,then why is strlen() function working for integer arrays.

Comment: `strlen()` does **not** work for integer arrays. If it *appears to work*, that's **Undefined Behaviour** manifesting itself.

Comment: A very short example proving the base assumption is wrong: `char array[] = {0, 1, 2}`. A  string is a *zero-terminated* array of characters.

Comment: "Array can hold any datatype" – no, not in C. "why is strlen() function working for integer arrays" – it only works when the integral type of the array is `char` or `signed char` or `unsigned char`. It doesn't work with any integer type in general.

Comment: I don't remember there is a String type in C... What you call string is just an array of char. And use strlen on integer array just doesn't fit.

Comment: when you understand how important is the 0x0 or '\0' or Null char... you will not need this question anymore...

Answer (score 2):

An array is a sequence of data item of homogeneous value(same type. A string in C, is an array of characters ending with the NUL-terminator(`\0`).

The declaration for the `strlen` function is

```
size_t strlen(const char *str)
```

Which means that it takes an argument of type `const char*`, not an `int*` or an `int[]`. So it won't work for integer arrays. You'll get a warning if you try to pass it as an argument to `strlen`-

```
warning: passing argument 1 of ‘strlen’ from incompatible pointer type
```

And then, if you try to execute the program, you'll run into [UB(Undefined Behaviour)](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) which means that anything can happen including segmentation faults,crashes,formatting you hard disk etc etc etc